# Android register connection to windows as an HID client

Tags: android, bluetooth, mouse, driver, hid

after doing some preliminary searching, I was not able to find much information on how to register android as an HID client. That is, I would like to be able to send mouse controls from my phone to to the PC, essentially controlling my pc from droid as if the droid was a mouse. Seems simple...as windows already has default generic mouse drivers through the bluetooth HID channel...however...

After doing some reading it seems like android is blocking HID Interrupt and HID Control channels on top of the L2CAP channel... that is, I am not able to register my droid as HID Mouse on Windows...

Here is something that I found on google code of someone trying it...
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/73f03a22963b356d?pli=1

Can someone with a bit more knowledge on the subject confirm that android does not allow you to do this...

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK your phone needs to be rooted

Look at this project: [AndroHID](http://code.google.com/p/androhid/)

Comment: only does keyboard apparently